# What major thing would I miss if I program my deep packet inspection program in Windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, network-programming

I am starting to write a deep packet inspection traffic classifier for a project I'm involved. I'm kind of new to programming and newbie in Linux. Using C++ for my program, am I missing a major advantage that Linux might offer to me instead of Windows?

I'm not referring to opinion-based arguments, Is there any major technical functionality that Linux OS would offer?

Comment: I don't understand what makes you think you could miss anything. Windows still has to receive the entire packet.

Comment: @EJP: For example, IIRC the "portable" libpcap when running on Linux can modify packets before they reach the socket, while on Windows it can only receive a copy, but the socket receives the original.  (winpcap can also create packets, but that's not quite the same as modifying them)

Comment: You need to go deeper: your own network card driver could have seen packets directly from the wire, long before any socket.

Answer (score 3):

Today, OS (Linux or Windows) is less relevant than the networking library you want to use. A good library should be OS agnostic. So basically, I do not think you miss something.

Comment: Florian what is the feature in OS that makes it less relevant?

Comment: @Nobody Nothing. It's the availability of portable libraries like libpcap, whose Windows version is Winpcap. If you're not using this, you should be.